# Display OpenLayers map on node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, openlayers

I'm using openlayers module on drupal. I have latitude and longitude fields (no geofield module), and a few nodes. I've created a view to mark these locations on the map. So far so good. Additionally, I would like to display a map on each node with the latitude and longitude of each location. For that purpose, I tried adding a block display, using contextual filters added nid, but it didn't work for me? Has anybody tried doing that before?

Regards,

Comment: Hey any luck buddy? I am trying the same, I am not sure if we can show the overlays on maps in each node. All the tutorials asks us to create a new "Page" to do it. But how can we display the same map with our new data layer in each node? No matter how much I modify, I get back normal map in each node.

Comment: Sorry Raj, I had forgotten I ever asked this question. I simply followed http://www.interworks.com/blogs/mmueggenborg/2012/01/03/setting-drupal-7-locations-map and it got me to be able to work out engelsizturkiye.info. Do you still need help with it?

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I could do it finally by following an example. I was doing a mistake due to which the KML layer was not being rendered. Thank you for the blog link you posted, this is more detailed than what I referred. This is the outcome: http://www.rkmission-shivanahalli.org/nature-guide/?q=node/17

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to install geofield and geofield map. Then set geofield to display as a map. This will display as a Google map, which may clash with you other OpenLayers maps.

The other option might (yet to try) be to create a map view with nid argument and embed it into your node as field using the EVA module.